# When is new Guid() 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000,when not?

Tags: c#

I hava a large log C# file. My client complained that some SessionIds are 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000.
First method

```
public static StartServiceLog CreateStartServiceLog(string serviceName, Guid sessionId = new Guid(), Device device = null, string userId = null)
{
    if (device == null)
    {
        device = CreateDeviceInfo();
    }

    return new StartServiceLog(device, DateTime.UtcNow, sessionId, userId, new List<string>() { serviceName });
}
```

I call this method

```
    var session = new StartSessionLog
    {
        Sid = sessionId,
        Device = device,
        Timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow,
    };
    return session;
```

How to find out when  SessionIds are going to have all zeros or will be overwritten?

Comment: new Guid() returns 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000, Guid.NewGuid() generates a new random number

Comment: `Guid` is a value-type; `new AnyValueType()` is *basically* a "initialize with all zeros/nulls"; use `Guid.NewGuid()` instead

Comment: @TimSchmelter I added few more lines,take a look.

Comment: That is an easy enough mistake to make.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`System.Guid` is a struct, not a class. This means that its parameterless constructor cannot do any work, and so, `new Guid() == default`.

The default value for structs is all members set to default values. In the case of `Guid`, it is a bunch of numbers, so its visual representation ends up all zeros.

To create a `Guid` with an actual value, you need to call the [`Guid.NewGuid()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid.newguid?view=net-5.0#System_Guid_NewGuid) static method. This cannot be done within the default parameter initializer, so you would need to change your method to take the [nullable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1?view=net-5.0) `Guid?` instead:

```
public static void Foo(string etcetera, Guid? sessionId = null)
{
    if (sessionId == null)
    {
        sessionId = Guid.NewGuid();
    }

    // Do something with `sessionId.Value`
}
```

Comment: Oddly enough, even if the default constructor *does* do work (if you coded it in IL), it would not be executed in this case, this *really is* a case of `default(Guid)` it's just initialized to all 0's. You can see this in IL [on Sharplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgPgAgTARgLACgYGYAE9MGFMDeqmJ2WMALJgLIAUA4gK5gAmmA5s2wLyYsCmAMwCGjCMACUhYqQC+MkhmxVqcBlw4beAO34B3TE1a0JUoilKZ5KWUA)

Comment: @Charlieface I don't know much about IL, but is it even legal to define a default constructor for value types there? Either way, it makes sense that the C# compiler assumes C# rules for optional parameter initialization.

Comment: Nothing to stop you in IL, but yeah, C# would not execute it.

Answer (score 7):

I think you are mistakenly using `new Guid()` instead of `Guid.NewGuid()` to generate a brand new Guid.

Look at this example:

```
Console.WriteLine(new Guid());
Console.WriteLine(Guid.NewGuid());
```

Which outputs:

```
00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
1b8640a1-a9d0-42c5-aaff-a87831687792
```

The problem is that `Guid.NewGuid()` cannot be used as a default value for a parameter because it is not a compile-time constant.

Instead you could do something like:

```
public static StartServiceLog CreateStartServiceLog(string serviceName, Guid? sessionId = null, Device device = null, string userId = null)
{
    if (sessionId == null)
        sessionId = Guid.NewGuid();
    ...
```

Set the default value of `sessionId` to be `NULL` and then if it is then create a new guid correctly in your method.

Answer (score 2):

`new Guid()` doesn't generate a new `Guid`, it just returns all zeroes. Use `Guid.NewGuid()` instead (which of course can't be used as default value).

A simple pattern to use this in an optional argument would be something like this:

```
void DoSomething(Guid? id = default)
{
  id ??= Guid.NewGuid();
}
```